# Modular equipment to detect N and L swap in single-phase 230VAC feed?

Tags: power-supply, mains, single-phase

Say I have a single-phase feed with N and L (no PE) that comes into a distribution board. I have equipment for detecting over/undervoltage, but what equipment can I use in order to detect someone upstream swapping the L and N lines?

Comment: It's the wire that does not wiggle at all in reference to earth. But if it is a two line feed, what difference it will make which one is neutral or live, and maybe neither is neutral, if there is for exampl 115 VAC on both wires in respect to PE?

Comment: There are these screw drivers with a little neon bulb inside..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot tell without a PE reference.

This is why all design using mains inputs treat **both** wires as **Live**, regardless of the mains being LL, LN or NL.

It also makes no difference. You will measure the same VAC from wire 1 to wire 2 as vice versa.